# Removing array elements when each element can reference an index in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
{
    "childA": 156,
    "childB": 2422,
    "color": "df7f00",
    "id": 124,
    "posA": {
        "x": 5,
        "y": -46,
        "z": 11
    },
    "posB": {
        "x": 5,
        "y": -46,
        "z": 11
    },
    "shapeId": "4a1b886b-913e-4aad-b5b6-6e41b0db23a6",
    "xaxisA": 1,
    "xaxisB": 1,
    "zaxisA": 2,
    "zaxisB": 2
}
```

First some important context. Playing with an array in JavaScript. So I have an object with an array "bodies", and inside of those is an array of "childs". The code posted above is one of those childs.

Now I've written some javascript to delete certain childs based on their shapeId with the .filter() method, but this creates an issue with the "childA" and "childB" values which point to a certain index in the childs array. May be worth noting that not all elements in the childs array have the child* properties. I'm having a very hard time thinking through how to accomplish removing one element, and then fixing the "childA", "childB", etc... values of other elements in the childs array that get thrown off as a result.

I think I'll need to check for childs before the deleted element that reference a child after the deleted element and adjust it, as well as childs after the deleted element that reference a child before it. I'll also need to remove references to elements that get removed from the array. I cannot work out how to accomplish this though.

Please forgive my ignorance as I'm learning, and thank you for any help.

Here's the object with the first few childs:

```
{
"bodies": [{
    "childs": [{
        "color": "560202",
        "controller": {
            "audioIndex": 1,
            "controllers": null,
            "id": 28253,
            "joints": null,
            "pitch": 1,
            "volume": 100
        },
        "pos": {
            "x": -13,
            "y": -18,
            "z": 3
        },
        "shapeId": "4c6e27a2-4c35-4df3-9794-5e206fef9012",
        "xaxis": 2,
        "zaxis": 1
    }, {
        "color": "0a1d5a",
        "controller": {
            "audioIndex": 1,
            "controllers": null,
            "id": 28248,
            "joints": null,
            "pitch": 1,
            "volume": 100
        },
        "pos": {
            "x": 16,
            "y": -13,
            "z": 3
        },
        "shapeId": "4c6e27a2-4c35-4df3-9794-5e206fef9012",
        "xaxis": 1,
        "zaxis": -2
    },
```

Comment: Isn't it an object?

Comment: please add the array, you are talking about.

Comment: If those are index values and not id value then you probably have to update all elements after the deleted element to use index-1.

Comment: What I posted is an object yes, but it's an element of the childs array.

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would avoid using indexes directly, since it could be very tricky to keep them up-to-date on a reliable way; one possible alternative would be to add some 'id' field to the object, so it could be accessed independently of the position on the array; you could also have an auxiliar object containing the ids as keys and the object references themselves as the values, in order to speed up the access.

The way the data is structured dos not seem very amenable to editing, so aciting directly on the original structure would only be viable if the intentions are making something very simple. For more complex edits, converting it into an internal, more convenient, representation, making the alterations on top of that, and then converting it back to the original representation could actually save time in terms of debugging headaches.

Comment: The object is actually created by a video game as a blueprint for a creation so I can't change how one child references another.

Comment: I see... so, what are you intending to use the object for? Due to the way it is structured, it's not very amenable to editing, so aciting directly on the original structure would only be viable if you are making something very simple; if you intend to make complex edits and then save the edited result back, converting it into an internal, more convenient representation, making the alterations on top of that, and then convert it back to the original representation could actually save you time.

Comment: Overall the intent was to delete all items of a certain type from the childs array which I was doing using the .filter method on the childs array, but it kept leaving me with an invalid blueprint in game.Traced down the issue to those childA (childB, etc..) properties that didn't point to any Id

Comment: I see; if that's the only transformation you need, one option would be to, at the same time that you filter the elements, you could also populate an auxiliar  with the indexes of the positions that were filtered out, and then use that to know which indexes you would need to decrement.

Comment: Sorry for the double post here, can't seem to edit my last comment.

Comment: Though, thinking better about it, converting the object to a more convenient structure and then converting it back still feels easier to keep track of than directly decrementing the indexes according to which elements were deleted, unless you're just deleting one element at once.

Comment: I have a tendency to hit enter, sorry. That's good advice. I sort of stumbled my way into something like that after reading your answer. http://pastebin.com/r6vUZXaa The same issue is there, and after deleting all of a certain item in game and then comparing it with a copy sent through my script I see I'm definitely missing something because the game changed the child* references by more than the amount of items that were deleted, and not all changed equally. It's extremely confusing, but I think your solution is sound. I just need to understand what the game is doing a little better. TY!

Comment: Not sure what happened but I had a lengthy response that disappeared, I really dislike this comment system. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/r6vUZXaa) That's what I'm using now, but it's causing the same issue. I did a little test and took the same blueprint and ran one copy through my script and the other I edited normally through the game and the child* references (which only appear in the joints array, which is actually seperate from the bodies [and childs] array) were off by more than the number of items I deleted. Basically your solution is sound, my understanding of the game is not. TY!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post the code for what I'm using at present, which is actually providing a valid blueprint in-game now. I hope it's not bad manners to post an answer to your own question, but it is working now and I'm eager to share it. There are likely much more efficient ways of handling this, but here's what I've got:

```
function deleteObjects() {
var IdCleanup = new Array();
objectCount = 0;
var cleanupCount = 0;
var jointCleanupCount = 0;
var oChildIndex = 0;

var childACleanup = 0;
var childBCleanup = 0;
var childCCleanup = 0;

// Loop through the array manually and remove the id of elements being removed from thejson.bodies[i].childs[j].controller.controllers[*].id
// fruits.splice(index, howmany);

/*  for(var i = 0; i < thejson.bodies.length; i++) { thejson.bodies[i].childs = thejson.bodies[i].childs.filter(checkObject); } */


/***************************************************************************************************************
To do list:
1. Add thejson.bodies[*].childs[*].controller.id to IdCleanup list.
2. Remove thejson.bodies[*].childs[*] 
3. Adjust thejson.joints[*].childA, thejson.joints[*].childB, .... references.

4. Remove thejson.bodies[*].childs[*].controller.controllers[*].id values in the IdCleanup list.
***************************************************************************************************************/



// One pass to delete the child objects, and add the deleted child's IDs to list.
for(var i = 0; i < thejson.bodies.length; i++) {
     for(var j = 0; j < thejson.bodies[i].childs.length; j++) {

         // Shape matches dropdown menu value.
         if(thejson.bodies[i].childs[j].shapeId == document.getElementById("mySelect").value) {

             if(IdCleanup.indexOf(thejson.bodies[i].childs[j].controller.id) == -1) {
                 // Add this ID to the list of ones to remove.
                 IdCleanup[IdCleanup.length] = thejson.bodies[i].childs[j].controller.id;
             }

             // Remove this child.
             thejson.bodies[i].childs.splice(j, 1);
             j--;
             oChildIndex--;// Keeping the overall index accurate.

             // Adjust joints array.
             if(thejson.joints != undefined) {
                for(var k = 0; k < thejson.joints.length; k++) {
                    if(thejson.joints[k].childA) {
                        var idx = thejson.joints[k].childA;

                        if(idx < oChildIndex) {

                        } else if(idx > oChildIndex) {
                            thejson.joints[k].childA--;
                            jointCleanupCount++;
                            childACleanup++;
                        } else if(idx == oChildIndex) {

                        }
                    }

                    if(thejson.joints[k].childB) {
                        var idx = thejson.joints[k].childB;

                        if(idx < oChildIndex) {

                        } else if(idx > oChildIndex) {
                            thejson.joints[k].childB--;
                            jointCleanupCount++;
                            childBCleanup++;
                        } else if(idx == oChildIndex) {

                        }
                    }

                    if(thejson.joints[k].childC) {
                        var idx = thejson.joints[k].childC;

                        if(idx < oChildIndex) {

                        } else if(idx > oChildIndex) {
                            thejson.joints[k].childC--;
                            jointCleanupCount++;
                            childCCleanup++;
                        } else if(idx == oChildIndex) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            objectCount++;
        }

        oChildIndex++;
    }
}

// Second pass for cleaning up the IDs from thejson.bodies[i].childs[j].controller.controllers that need removed.
for(var i = 0; i < thejson.bodies.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < thejson.bodies[i].childs.length; j++) {
        var object = thejson.bodies[i].childs[j];

        // Check for controllers
        if(thejson.bodies[i].childs[j].controller && thejson.bodies[i].childs[j].controller.controllers != null) {
            for(var k = 0; k < thejson.bodies[i].childs[j].controller.controllers.length; k++) {

                if(IdCleanup.indexOf(thejson.bodies[i].childs[j].controller.controllers[k].id) != -1) {
                    // one of the controllers match an ID of one that was deleted. 

                    var idx = IdCleanup.indexOf(thejson.bodies[i].childs[j].controller.controllers[k].id);

                    thejson.bodies[i].childs[j].controller.controllers.splice(k,1);
                    k--;
                    cleanupCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var processLog = document.getElementById('processLog');
processLog.value = processLog.value +"\n"+ objectCount +" objects deleted.\n";
processLog.value = processLog.value + cleanupCount +" ID cleanup operations.\n";
processLog.value = processLog.value + jointCleanupCount +" joint cleanup operations.\n";
processLog.value = processLog.value + childACleanup +" A, "+ childBCleanup +" B, "+ childCCleanup +" C\n";
```

}

Originally this was just a loop through the bodies array, and then using .filter on each of the childs arrays checking for a corresponding shapeId. This caused the joints array (separate from the bodies (& childs) arrays) to point to the wrong index in the childs array. Haroldo_OK put me on the right track to fixing that. A few minutes ago it hit me that I wasn't keeping my overall child count (oChildCount :P) accurate when I would remove a child. So I decrement that count each time I remove a child and voila! It works!

Thank you very much, Haroldo_OK